# Getting Null value from SOQL Query in Handler for Roll Up Summary

Tags: apex, trigger

I want this Handler work as Roll Up Summary between Price__c on OpportunityLineItem and Total_Amount__c on Opportunity.

Trigger On OpportunityLineItem

```
trigger OpportunityLineItemTrigger on OpportunityLineItem (after insert,after update) {
    if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
        system.debug(trigger.new);
        OpportunityRollUp.OppLineItemRollUp(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Handler for this Trigger

```
public class OpportunityRollUp {
    public static void OppLineItemRollUp(List<OpportunityLineItem> newOppLineItem){
        List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

        List<Decimal> newOppPrice = new List<Decimal>();
        for(OpportunityLineitem oli : newOppLineItem){
            newOppPrice.add(oli.Price__c);
        }

        System.debug('newOppLineItem from trigger.new  '+newOppLineItem);

        Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>> m = new Map<Id,List<OpportunityLineItem>>();


        List<Opportunity> opp = [Select Id,Total_Amount__c,(Select Price__c,TotalPrice,Id from OpportunityLineItems) from Opportunity where Id IN (Select OpportunityId from opportunityLineItem where Id IN :newOppLineItem)];
        List<OpportunityLineItem> oliList = [Select Price__c,TotalPrice from OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId IN: Opp AND Price__c IN : newOppPrice];
        System.debug('Query of Oli'+oliList);

        for(OpportunityLineItem oli1 : newOppLineItem){
            if(m.containsKey(oli1.Id)){
                m.get(oli1.Id).add(oli1);
            }
            m.put(oli1.Id, new List<OpportunityLineItem>() );
        }
        System.debug('map value' +m);

        for(Opportunity o : opp){
            for(opportunityLineItem oli : o.OpportunityLineItems){
                if(o.Total_Amount__c == null){
                    o.Total_Amount__c = 0;
                }
                    o.Total_Amount__c = o.Total_Amount__c + oli.Price__c;
            }
            for(OpportunityLineItem oli1 : oliList){
                    o.Total_Amount__c = o.Total_Amount__c +oli1.Price__c;
            }
            oppList.add(o);
        }
        update oppList;
    }
}
```

Price__c field has value in newOppLineItem but Getting Null value of Price__c from oliList, can any one Explain how to retrieve Price__c field value from newOppLineItem and Why that query is returning Null value.

Comment: what value you have in this `Price__c` field written at `newOppPrice.add(oli.Price__c);`

Comment: it is just a decimal field, and during updating or Inserting the Opportunity Line Item, i am trying to insert/update this field, in order to check my Roll Up Functionality Functionality

Comment: what value you are getting. please add system debug to make sure you don't get null

Comment: Your code is working when updating existing OLIs except for the fact that the Opportunity is being updated with the OLI values twice. Are you seeing this NPE when inserting a new OLI?

Comment: On update its working fine, but on Inserting the new OrderLineItem error occurs  - "" Apex trigger OpportunityLineItemTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: OpportunityLineItemTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null. ""

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First things first, if you haven't used all of your available rollup summary fields on `Opportunity`, you should create a rollup summary field on `Opportunity` (that summarizes the `Price__c` field on `OpportunityLineItem`) to do this. Rollup summary fields are standard functionality, and it's almost always a better idea to try to use standard functionality before trying to "roll your own".

That aside, one of your comments on your question contains some very important details:

- You say that you are getting your error only when inserting a new `OpportunityLineItem`
- The error message that you're getting contains the following:

  > System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

If you dig into the error message a little more, and find the line number that your error is occurring on, I'd wager that it's on one of two lines, towards the bottom of your trigger helper

```
for(Opportunity o : opp){
    for(opportunityLineItem oli : o.OpportunityLineItems){
        if(o.Total_Amount__c == null){
            o.Total_Amount__c = 0;
        }
        // Your error is either occurring on the line below this one...
        o.Total_Amount__c = o.Total_Amount__c + oli.Price__c;
    }

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli1 : oliList){
        // ...or on the line below this one
        o.Total_Amount__c = o.Total_Amount__c +oli1.Price__c;
    }

    oppList.add(o);
}
```

Either `Total_Amount__c` on one of your `Opportunities` is null (less likely), or the `Price__c` on one of your `OpportunityLineItems` is null (more likely, especially before/after insert).

`Integer someVar = someInteger + null;` will give you the error that you've encountered.

The solution to this problem is to check for null values, and substitute null values with `0` when you find them. You could accomplish this by using a formula field (which would simply reference the `Price__c` field, and be set to treat blanks as zero), or you could take care of it in apex (using if/else or, my preferred method, the ternary operator).

```
for(Opportunity o : opp){
    for(opportunityLineItem oli : o.OpportunityLineItems){
        if(o.Total_Amount__c == null){
            o.Total_Amount__c = 0;
        }
        // You've already taken care of the null check for Total_Amount__c,
        //   so we just need to check Price__c here.
        // The syntax for the ternary operator is <boolean test> ? <value if true> : <value if false>
        // If oli.Price__c is null, we want to add 0, otherwise, add the value from
        //   oli.Price__c
        o.Total_Amount__c = o.Total_Amount__c + oli.Price__c == null ? 0 : oli.Price__c;
    }

    for(OpportunityLineItem oli1 : oliList){
        // Both Total_Amount__c and Price__c should be null checked here
        o.Total_Amount__c = o.Total_Amount__c == null ? 0 : o.Total_Amount__c + oli1.Price__c == null ? 0 : oli1.Price__c;
    }

    oppList.add(o);
}
```

Now that I've gotten handling your error out of the way, I can talk more about your `OpportunityRollUp` helper class.

There seems to be a few odd things about this class:

- Your `Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> m` doesn't seem to be used anywhere (and your loop to populate this map appears that it will always miss putting one `OpportunityLineItem` into the list for each `Opportunity`
- You have two queries, one on `Opportunity` that queries the associated `OpportunityLineItems`, and another that queries `OpportunityLineItem` based on `Price__c` and being related to any `Opportunity` from the previous query. I have no idea why you need this query (seems like you're just querying again for records that should be included in your first query)
- You appear to be using the results of this second query to add the `Total_Amount__c` and `Price__c` of a given `OpportunityLineItem` to an `Opportunity` that the `OpportunityLineItem` might not belong to. I have doubts that this is doing what you want it to do.

Beyond that, performing manual rollups like this (query for the parent object and all of its child records, loop through the child records, parent += child value) works, with the null checking that you need to do when rolling your own rollup code, it gets really tedious after you start rolling up more than a few fields this way.

There is a better way to do this.

You can use Aggregate functions in SOQL to do the heavy lifting here. If I were to re-write your code, it would look something like this:

```
public static void OppLineItemRollUp(List<OpportunityLineItem> newOppLineItem){
    // First, gather the set of Opportunties involved (or really, just their Ids)
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(OpportunityLineItem oli :newOppLineItem){
        oppIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);
    }

    // Next, use these OpportunityIds to query all related OLIs.
    // SUM() will do most of the work required for the rollup, and
    //   grouping by OpportunityId will ensure that only the related OLIs
    //   are used to get the result of SUM() for each Opportunity.
    // SUM() can handle null values just fine, so we don't need to perform any null
    //   checks later.
    List<AggregateResult> arList = [SELECT OpportunityId, SUM(Price__c) totalPrice FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :oppIds GROUP BY OpportunityId];

    // Finally, create a List to hold the Opportunities that need to be updated.
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

    for(AggregateResult ar :arList){
        // We can only fetch fields from an AggregateResult by using get(<field name>)
        // Doing so will always return data as a plain Object, so we'll need to do some casting.
        // We can use the SObject constructor to set the Id so we don't need to query 
        //   for the Opportunities first.
        oppsToUpdate.add(new Opportunity(
            Id = (Id)ar.get('OpportunityId'),
            Total_Amount__c = (Decimal)ar.get('totalPrice')
        ));
    }

    // dml update the opps like normal
    update oppsToUpdate;
}
```

~13 lines of code (depending on how you count) is better than the ~28 that your current implementation uses.

The one, big gotcha with this method is that while `SUM()` can handle null values just fine, the end result will be null if all of the values that you're summing are null.

If you need to use the result of a SOQL `SUM()` in another calculation (in apex), then you will still need to perform a null check at some point.